# Using both Arquillian and PowerMock in the same JUnit test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock, jboss-arquillian

I would like to use the features of both Arquillian and PowerMock in the same JUnit 4 test.

The problem is that both products are JUnit `Runner`s which should be used with `@RunWith`, and this is not possible to use multiple `@RunWith` on the same test class, or to put multiple `Runner`s class in the same `@RunWith` annotation.

Do you know any way to do that ?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question in order to be more precise.

Comment: Matthew, can you please look to my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799352/how-to-use-powermock-with-arquillian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use PowerMock without using the runner if you use the [PowerMockRule](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) (which is a [TestRule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestRule.java)). From the PowerMockRule:

> Since version 1.4 it's possible to bootstrap PowerMock using a JUnit
>   Rule instead of using the PowerMockRunner and the RunWith annotation.
>   This allows you to use other JUnit runners while still benefiting from
>   PowerMock's functionality. You do this by specifying:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class);
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    // Tests goes here
    ...
}
```

See also the answers to [Junit Parameterized tests together with Powermock - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454473/junit-parameterized-tests-together-with-powermock-how) and the following thread in the PowerMock google group: [Using PowerMock without the RunWith?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/powermock/D33yS93xzHM).

Comment: @Mattew Farwell: This does not work for me. I get: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: PowerMockRule can only be used with the system classloader but was loaded by ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader`. What can I do to use Arquillian and PowerMock together?

Answer (score 2):

No, you either need to:

- use one and create a test base class that does the things you wanted the other runner to do.
- separate your test into multiple tests, each using different runners.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit4 only supports one @RunWith annotation, and JUnit4's @RunWith annotation doesn’t accept multiple runners.

**Reference:** [project13](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/)