# Running PowerMock with Enclosed class

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, junit4

I have a problem about running PowerMock with @Runwith(Enclosed.class) in pararell.

My test class structure:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(UnitBuild.class)

public class ut_QueueBuild{

    @Test
    public void someTest(){}

    public static InnerTestClass{

        @Test
        public void someInnerTest(){}
    }

}
```

Before using powerMock I just used:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class unitTestClass {
...
```

But since I am using PowerMock there is no possibility to use in pararell
@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)
and
@Runwith(Enclosed.class)

How can I solve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `PowerMockRunnerDelegate` and do:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Enclosed.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyStaticClass.class)
public class ut_QueueBuild{

    @Test
    public void someTest(){}

    public static InnerTestClass{

        @Test
        public void someInnerTest(){}
    }

}
```

This applies also to other runners, like the `Parametrized`.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit4 only supports one @RunWith annotation, and JUnit4's @RunWith annotation doesn’t accept multiple runners.[Reference: project13](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/)

Possible duplicate question but here's the answer from this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496690/2964890) @Matthew Farwell

> No, you either need to:
>
> use one and create a test base class that does the things you wanted
>   the other runner to do. separate your test into multiple tests, each
>   using different runners.