# How to stub static method using Arquillian

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, stubbing

Is there any way to stub a static method using Arquillian with Junit?
Example:

```
class A {
 public static String methodA() {
  if(...){
   return "Real";
  }
  return "Stub";
 }
}

class B {
 public String methodB(){
  String test = A.methodA();
  if(test.equals("Real"){
    // some code here
  } else {
    // some code here
  }
 }
}
```

I need to test methodB() without executing methodA, with stubbing it and expecting its result, is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Arquillian itself can do this, you need something else like PowerMock as well. So your question is a duplicate of [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496552/using-both-arquillian-and-powermock-in-the-same-junit-test) of sorts.