# How to use PowerMock with Arquillian?

Tags: java, junit, classloader, powermock, jboss-arquillian

I tried to use PowerMockRule in a JUnit test that uses arquillian but I get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PowerMockRule can only be used with the system classloader but was loaded by ModuleClassLoader for Module

I want to test something like this:

```
 @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
 @PrepareForTest(WARRRAworkffsTest.class)
 public class WARRRAworkffsTest  {

@Rule  
   public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();  


   @Deployment(testable=true)
        public static EnterpriseArchive createDeployment() throws MalformedURLException {

// yadayada

return ear;


}


@Test
public void createTest(){
PowerMock usage
}

}
```

Can you help me to solve this? Or if you have another idea how should i do it, will be great.

Comment: I was not able to get it up and running, but have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496552/using-both-arquillian-and-powermock-in-the-same-junit-test

Comment: @Adelina Dimachi: Did you got it? I have the same problem. Your linked post does not help either.