# Workaround for JUnitParams as this cant be used along with PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

I am using PowerMock for my unit testing and JUnitParams cannot be used along with that because of the following issue,

[Junit Parameterized tests together with Powermock - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454473/junit-parameterized-tests-together-with-powermock-how)

Is there any workaround to pass bunch of strings to my test method and run the same test case for each string

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [PowerMock Rule](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule)?

Comment: I am using an older version of PowerMock, I think PowerMockRule is in 4.7